# How to invalidate Web API cache from another Controller(ASP.NET Web API CacheOutput Library)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, outputcache, asp.net-cache

I have used ASP.NET Web API CacheOutput Library for my asp.net project for web API and it working fine, but have another controller from where I have a POST method and I would like to invalidate my cache from that controller.

```
[AutoInvalidateCacheOutput]
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{ 
    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 100, ServerTimeSpan = 100)]
    public IEnumerable<DropDown> GetData()
    {
        //Code here
    }
}


public class EmployeesController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEmployee (EmployeeEntity empInfo)
    {
        //Code Here
    }
}
```

I would like to invalidate Employees Cache when there is add\update in employee controller.

Comment: I am not sure but [NoCache] attribute can help.

Comment: I want Cache, but just would like to invalidate when there is change in employee controller

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is little tricky, but you can get it in this way:

**1. On your WebApiConfig:**

```
// Registering the IApiOutputCache.    
var cacheConfig = config.CacheOutputConfiguration();
cacheConfig.RegisterCacheOutputProvider(() => new MemoryCacheDefault());
```

*We will need of it to get the IApiOutputCache from GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Properties, if we let the default properties' setup happen the property with the IApiOutputCache won't exists on MVC BaseController request.*

**2. Create a WebApiCacheHelper class:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApi.OutputCache.Core.Cache;
using WebApi.OutputCache.V2;

namespace MideaCarrier.Bss.WebApi.Controllers
{
    public static class WebApiCacheHelper
    {
        public static void InvalidateCache<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
        {
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            // Gets the cache key.
            var outputConfig = config.CacheOutputConfiguration();
            var cacheKey = outputConfig.MakeBaseCachekey(expression);

            // Remove from cache.
            var cache = (config.Properties[typeof(IApiOutputCache)] as Func<IApiOutputCache>)();
            cache.RemoveStartsWith(cacheKey);
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Then, call it from your EmployeesController.CreateEmployee action:**

```
public class EmployeesController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEmployee (EmployeeEntity empInfo)
    {
        // your action code Here.
        WebApiCacheHelper.InvalidateCache((EmployeeApiController t) => t.GetData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using ASP.Net 4.0 and WebApi.OutputCache.V2 is available only in ASP.net 4.5 do you have any other suggestion for work with ASP.Net 4.0? or i have to upgrade my solution to asp.net 4.5

Comment: I don't know, I've never used WebApi.OutputCache with ASP .NET 4.0.

Comment: Seems your solution will work for 4.5 as it doesn't solved my problem but accepting as answer hope that will help to others.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: In the example above, if t.GetData() takes a parameter, one can pass anything that compiles. This method removes all cached entries associated with the provided expression, irrespective of the parameter values in the expression.